# Coordination de verbes transitifs indirects (à l'infinitif) avec complément commun : analyse, cohérence ?

Tags: prépositions, verbes, conjonctions, coordination, transitivité

Il s'agit du sujet de la compatibilité des verbes pour fins de coordination (avec la conjonction *et*) quand ils partagent le même complément (par ellipse, distributivité), plus particulièrement des verbes transitifs indirects qui introduisent donc leur complément avec une préposition (*à, de* etc.) :

> **(1)** Penser à [tr. ind. ; direct, sans *à*, serait *concevoir* etc.] et discuter de [tr. ind.] quelque chose.
> (2) Penser à quelque chose et en discuter.
>
> ---
>
> (3A) Au dedans et au dehors de la ville.
>  (3B) Aux environs ou dans la ville [peu correct]
>  (3C) Aux environs de ou dans la ville.
> [pas incorrect mais peu usité]
>  (4A) Une grammaire grecque et
> systématique. (X)
>  (4B) Une grammaire grecque systématique.
>  (5) J'enlace
> et je berce son âme. (Baudelaire)
>  (6) La dignité de l'homme
> consistoit dans son innocence à user et dominer sur les creatures.
> (Pascal)
>  (7) Le maître d’hôtel n'aurait pas osé et n'aurait même pas
> eu assez d'imagination pour prédire une guerre longue et indécise.
> (Proust)
>  (8) L'esprit qui l'anime fera triompher le pays aux côtés et
> sur le même rang que ses vaillants et chers alliés. (de Gaulle, 6 juin
> 1943)
>  (9) On le voyait au passage entrer ou sortir de son cabinet.
> (Pagnol)
>  (10) Entrer et sortir de.
>
> [ Exemples extraits des §§ 260-269, 1042, *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et
> Goose, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup> ]

Dans le premier exemple, *penser à* introduit un complément indirect dont on fait l'ellipse du régime (*quelque chose*) de la préposition (*à*) pour le présenter plus loin avec *discuter*, lui aussi transitif indirect. On aura assurément le réflexe de remanier avec un pronom (2). La cohérence des régimes quand deux verbes partagent un même complément devient une préoccupation surtout au 16e (LBU14). Les exemples (3-10) illustrent différents usages de la coordination, une certaine logique, différents choix, et certaines compositions possiblement plus figées etc.

---

- Dans la phrase (1), en termes d'analyse (grammaticale) qu'est-ce qui
  se trouve coordonné au juste (un verbe avec une préposition,
  qu'est-ce que c'est comme unité grammaticale) ? Ou ne peut-on
  analyser (1) autrement qu'en contexte d'une proposition avec un verbe
  conjugué (9) mais avec un truc moins figé que dans cet exemple ? En
  résumé à quelle catégorie de coordination appartient l'exemple (1) et
  l'exemple (1) tel quel est-il au final une phrase, une locution,
  voire une équation ; devrait-on y ajouter une virgule avant *quelque
  chose* ?
- Considère-t-on que même si on a le même type de transitivité des
  verbes dans la phrase (1), qu'il y a néanmoins incohérence du
  résultat quand on partage ainsi le complément en utilisant l'ellipse,
  ou considère-t-on que cette construction est acceptable ? Cette
  locution semble-t-elle plus ou moins acceptable que la coordination
  de verbes dont l'un est transitif direct par exemple (pour un sens
  recherché), comme possiblement la phrase (7 ; *oser prédire*/*ne
  (même) pas avoir assez d'imagination pour prédire*) alors
  qu'évidemment on n'a pas de préposition avec un des verbes pour le
  complément (direct) ? **En résumé est-ce qu'on peut coordonner ces
  verbes et leur faire partager le même complément de cette manière (1),
  est-ce un choix comme un autre** ?

Comment: On peut simplifier la question?

Comment: You just remind me why as a child I was terrorized by grammar at school :)

Comment: Pas de problème. La nouvelle mouture est plus claire que l'initiale mais on y trouve encore aux moins six questions et elles sont de tout façon bien trop pointues et techniques pour qu'un simple amateur comme moi songe à se hasarder à tenter d'y répondre...

Comment: @jlliagre Merci, je comprends. Pour moi, aussi amateur, le premier para. de questions est simplement un prérequis à l'analyse que je ne réussis pas à faire. Pour l'instant je vais mettre en gras l'essence de la question. À ce stade-ci je ne sais même pas si en général un francophone accepte la construction du tout...

Answer (score 1):

Je ne suis pas certain d'avoir compris la question. En gros tu veux savoir si la phrase suivante :

> Je pense à mes vacances, et en discute avec mes collègues.

... peut se dire :

> 1) Je pense et discute de mes vacances avec mes collègues.

... ou se dirait plutôt :

> 2) Je pense **à** et discute de mes vacances avec mes collègues.

... ?

Je ne connais pas la règle, mais je dirais que la 2) est forcément correcte puisqu'elle respecte la construction des verbes, tandis que la 1) est peut-être devenue correcte, à force d'utilisation.

Comment: Merci ! Pas exactement (se dirait avec ou sans le _à_) mais votre réponse est utile. C'est que penser qqc., penser, et penser à quelque chose sont en résumé 3 sens différents, et donc _penser mes vacances_ et _penser à mes vacances_ sont distincts. Mais de manière fort intéressante (pour moi), vous ne semblez pas vous soucier outre mesure d'avoir un truc où on a la préposition puis la coordination tout de suite après (_à et_). Plus encore, j'ai même l'impression que vous sous-entendez que le sens de _je pense mes vacances_ a glissé vers celui de _je pense à mes vacances_ dans ce genre...

Comment: ... de coordination. Un peu comme avec _entrer et sortir de_ ? Avez-vous pensé aux différents sens du verbe _penser_ selon que l'emploi est transitif direct, indirect ou intransitif, ou parlez-vous uniquement de syntaxe/grammaire ? La sémantique et la syntaxe/grammaire sont-elles davantage en accord, avec l'un ou l'autre de vos deux derniers exemples ?

Comment: Je parlais uniquement du problème de syntaxe/grammaire : "faut-il mettre le *à* après *pense* si l'on met un *et*". J'aurais pu prendre un autre verbe : "Je vais *manger au* restaurant puis *sortir du* restaurant" devient "Je vais *manger au* puis *sortir du* restaurant". Concernant le sens-même du verbe *penser qqc* ou *penser à qqc*, *penser qqc* signifie plutôt *réfléchir à un plan*, *prévoir*. "Je pense mes vacances" signifierait "Je prévois le déroulement de mes vacances", c'est-à-dire quel vol, quel hôtel, le déroulement du séjour. C'est donc une planification d'un événement à venir.

Comment: Je vais réfléchir à ça. Si vous retouchez votre propos, je vous invite à y inclure certaines des idées dont vous traitez en commentaire. Merci !