# Succession de verbes ou groupes nominaux suivis d'une préposition

Tags: prépositions, verbes, syntaxe, coordination

J'ai édité car en réalité, le problème est plus général que celui des verbes.

Existe-t-il une règle pour les cas de verbes ou groupes nominaux suivis d'une préposition différente, que l'on fait se succéder ?

Exemple :

On dit *entrer **dans** la maison* et *sortir **de** la maison*.

Comment construire ?

- Utiliser la dernière préposition ?

  > Il ne fait qu'entrer et sortir de la maison.
- Utiliser les deux prépositions ?

  > Il ne fait qu'entrer dans et sortir de la maison.
- Changer la formulation ?

  > Il ne fait qu'entrer dans la maison et en sortir.
  >
  > Il ne fait qu'entrer dans la maison et sortir de la maison.
  >
  > Il ne fait qu'entrer et sortir.

  etc.

Le problème se pose également avec des groupes nominaux.

Le chien se promène *aux environs de la maison* et *dans la maison* ne devrait pas pouvoir s'écrire *le chien se promène aux environs et dans la maison*.

Mon but n'est pas de trouver la meilleure phrase pour cet exemple, mais de connaître la règle.

Voici le sujet qui m'a fait poser la question : http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=12281

Comment: Personnellement, "Il ne fait qu'entrer et sortir de la maison." me parait tellement naturelle que je pense que la règle est qu'il ne faut utiliser que la préposition du dernier verbe...

Comment: « Il ne fait qu'entrer dans et sortir de la maison. » Celle là, définitivement pas.

Comment: Ton exemple est un peu en marge de ta question parce que le verbe "entrer" peut très bien ne pas prendre de préposition (comme "sortir", d'ailleurs). Est-ce que tu aurais un autre exemple avec 2 verbes qui **doivent** avoir une préposition pour conserver leur sens ?

Comment: Intéressante question, je ne craint qu'une telle règle n'existe néanmoins.

Comment: @SteffX L'exemple est correct puisque dans ce contexte, on veut bien dire *entrer dans la maison*, et non *entrer la maison* ou *entrer de la maison*. Qu'on applique ou pas le *de* à *entrer* dans la phrase *entrer et sortir de la maison*, il y a un problème puisqu'on ne retrouve pas *entrer dans*. J'édite ma question puisqu'il ne s'agit pas que des verbes, mais également des groupes nominaux qu'on veut faire suivre d'une préposition.

Comment: C'est aussi une question sur la coordination, voir [ceci](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/21476).

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ Effectivement, en en plus j'avais proposé une réponse (qui est plutôt une question d'ailleurs).

Comment: À mon avis vous avez accroché sur le mauvais problème dans ces formulations. La question est bien plus simple: la locution "entrer et sortir" est utilisé pour indiquer une seule action, et c'est pourquoi il ne faut pas écrire "entrer dans et sortir de". C'est aussi pourquoi la forme simplifiée reste "Il ne fait qu'entrer et sortir".

Answer (score 2):

Il n'existe pas à mon sens de règle clairement définie. Je pense qu'il s'agit d'une règle implicite de bon sens.

Si on devait définir une règle de "bon sens" serait de ne pas préciser la proposition et sa contre proposition quand il n'y a pas d'ajout utile d'information. Et s'il y a ajout d'information, faire tourner les deux verbes (ou groupes nominaux) contraires autour de l'idée commune qui les relie.

Ainsi pour l'exemple du chien, il n'est pas nécessaire de préciser qu'il peut se balader "**dans la maison** et ses alentours*" mais plutôt **qu'il ne peut pas s'en éloigner**.

Ou encore pour le premier exemple, rajouter une indication sur la succession des événements (car il ne peut pas entrer et sortir en même temps) comme :

Il n'a fait qu'entrer puis ressortir **de la maison**

*ou autre*

Bref, l'idée sur une éventuelle règle tacite de bon sens serait

1. De ne pas préciser une information n'apportant pas d'information supplémentaire
2. D'organiser les verbes ou groupes nominaux autour de l'idée commune les regroupant

   J'espère avoir répondu à ta question.

Comment: Merci, mais honnêtement ça ne répond pas à ma question. Le point important ce n'est pas comment articuler les propositions et de savoir si elles sont pertinentes, c'est *que devient la préposition de la première proposition quand on enchaîne deux propositions qui n'ont pas la même préposition*.

Comment: Alors dans ce cas précis, où les deux prépositions (à, chez, dans, de, entre, jusque, hors, par, pour, sans et vers) ne sont pas identiques, il est impératif de donner à la phrase un sens ordonné soit temporellement, soit matériellement.

Ainsi, la phrase est séparée en deux, avec les deux idées distinctes. (si bien sûr, elle apporte une information utile)

Comment: Dans ton exemple (qui reprend le mien) *"Il n'a fait qu'entrer puis ressortir de la maison"*, quelque chose me dérange, parce que ça sous-entend *"Il n'a fait qu'entrer de la maison puis ressortir de la maison"*, alors qu'on dit bien évidemment *"entrer dans la maison"*. Et si on inversait les propositions, on écrirait probablement *"Il n'a fait que sortir et entrer dans la maison"* - on garderait la dernière préposition. A mon avis il y a forcément une règle, c'est le genre constructions qu'on emploie plusieurs fois par jour.

Comment: Effectivement, cet exemple est faux. Mais ici j'ai "triché" en ajoutant "**puis**", qui casse la phrase et nous évite de tout de suite avoir en tête "**entrer de la maison**". Une forme plus correcte aurait été "**Il n'a fait qu'entrer dans la maison, puis en ressortir.**" en ajoutant de façon très marquée l'ordination. Autre méthode, applicable, est de remplacer le "puis" par "ou" / "et" (...) en fonction du sens apporté à la phrase. Est-ce que cela semble plus acceptable et formel ? Autre ex : "*Des gens partent de cette maison ou vont vers celle-ci*" (même s'il n'y a ici aucun info utile)